# reinstalling packages using the command line

Tags: command-line

During installation of ubuntu on my chromebook certain packages were installed then removed...how do I reinstall them. Since several packages were removed at once can i reinstall them all at once, or one by oone, or is it possible to reinstall them at all. Thanks for any help you give.

Answer (score 2):

Of course.

You can do

```
sudo apt install {package1} {package2} {package3} {package4}
```

where you replace `{packageN}` will the package names you want to install. This does depend on the packages being available in the repositories.

The same can be done with downloaded .DEB's with

```
sudo dpkg -i {package}
```

You can also search for the name in Ubuntu software center if you do not know the package name and install from there or write down the package name it shows and install it with above `apt` command.